# FTP Plugin Not Showing Up

Tags: plugins, composer

I am working on a client site and trying to upload the following plugin:

https://github.com/craftcms/guest-entries

The directions instructed me to install the app via composer in my project folderj via composer.

Can I use composer to install the plugin into a random folder, then FTP upload the same into my client's craft plugins folder?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you on Craft 2 or Craft 3?

Comment: I just updated to Craft 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you FTP up the entire `vendor` folder, all of the same libraries should be available. Make sure it is properly installed locally, first.